# Docker run image_celery not able to detect redis

Tags: django, powershell, docker, redis, celery

I have a django application i want to run `redis` and `celery` using `docker run` command

after I build images using docker-compose file
I run two commands on different windows powershell

1. `docker run -it -p 6379:6379 redis`
2. `docker run -it image_celery`

my celery powershell is not able to detect redis

> [2020-02-08 13:08:44,686: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379/1: Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known..
>   Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

```
version: '3'
services:

  the-redis:
    image: redis:3.2.7-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ../data/redis:/data


  celery_5:
    build:
      context: ./mltrons_backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_celery
    volumes:
      - ./mltrons_backend:/code
      - /tmp:/code/static

    depends_on:
      - the-redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 4
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 25g
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

volumes:
  db_data:
    external: true
```

Dockerfile_celery

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


# Install Java
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt install -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer;

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code
ENV REDIS_HOST=redis://the-redis
ENV REDIS_PORT=6379



RUN pip install --upgrade 'sentry-sdk==0.7.10'
ENTRYPOINT celery -A mlbot_webservices worker -c 10 -l info

EXPOSE 8102
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mlbot_webservices.settings')

app = Celery('mltrons_training')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://the-redis:6379/'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://the-redis:6379/'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Comment: If you launch the containers using `docker-compose up`, does it work better?  There's some [networking setup that Compose will do for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) that your plain `docker run` commands don't replicate.

Comment: in case of docker-compose up it works perfectly but i want to run using docker-run is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected because when you start container as you do (`docker run IMAGE`), the containers use the default bridge network of Docker.
You can check it by inspecting that network : `docker network inspect bridge`.
The default bridge doesn't accept network resolution of the containers by container name as you do (`redis`).
Besides the default name of a container is not the image name but a generated name by docker.
That's why you get that error at runtime :

> Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379/1

Note that you can still reference containers belonging to the default bridge by their ip addresses, but that is generally undesirable because that hard code them from the client side.

[That works with Docker compose  because](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) :

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, **and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name**.

To be able to communicate by container name with `docker run`, you need :
- to add these containers in the same network but not the default one provided by Docker
- to give an explicit name to the container that you want to reference (while doing it for both container is good to monitor/manager it more simply) by the other.

For example create a user-defined bridge network and add the containers to that when you start them :

```
docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network
docker run -it -p 6379:6379 --network=my-bridge-network --name=redis redis
docker run -it --network=my-bridge-network --name=celery image_celery
```

Comment: (You also probably want to explicitly specify the containers' `--name`.)

Comment: @David Maze Sure. Thanks for the remember :)